Aircraft Movement statistics of Stockholm-Arlanda Airport of 2023
Does anyone know the Aircraft Movement statistics of Stockholm-Arlanda Airport of 2023? I tried searching everywhere on the web but couldn't find it. If you did find the Aircraft movement amount, please share the link of the site or file you found it on.

Although you already have an answer, in my opinion this type of question is more suited to Aviation.SE

I don't know what "everywhere" is, but Wikipedia says 92013.
The linked source (Swedavia statistics) tells us that for 2023:

Domestic: 22477
International: 69536


I didn't ask for the landings, but for the aircraft movements. There is a diference. Landings: This refers specifically to the event of an aircraft touching down on a runway and coming to a stop. It involves the final stages of a flight where the aircraft transitions from being airborne to being on the ground.
Movements: This term is broader and encompasses all types of activity an aircraft can perform on the ground. It includes not only landings but also takeoffs, taxiing to and from the runway, and parking.

@Talisman from Wikipedia "A movement is a landing or takeoff of an aircraft and includes both air transport movements and general aviation". You will never the number you want.

Copying back comments that were posted while it was migrated to aviation.SE before returning:

@Talisman With very few and very limited exceptions, the number of take-offs is equal to the number of landings. And one movement includes the whole operation from touching down to the parking stand (or vice-versa), I don't think anyone would could landing, taxiing and parking separately (if you want to, just multiply by 3!). There could be operations related to moving aircraft around (from a maintenance hangar to a parking spot and such), but I don't think anyone would count that as a "movement" in airport stats.
